# Attempt to read property "data_audit" on array laravel view loop foreach

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone I hope someone can help me I can't understand why I have this error.. what am I doing wrong in the @foreach of blade in the view thanks a lot this is my code..

Back :

```
$audits = DB::table('esiti_audit')->where('employee', $name)->select(['master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea', 'data_audit', 'esito'])->orderByDesc('data_audit')->get()->toArray();

$data = [];

foreach ($audits as $audit) {

 $areaKey =  "{$audit->master_zone}|{$audit->subarea}|{$audit->microarea}";

                $data[$areaKey][] = [
                    'esito' => $audit->esito,
                    'data_audit' => $audit->data_audit
                ];
            };
        };
```

Front

```
<div class="audit-daily-intestazione">
                                            @if (empty($data))
                                            @else
                                                @foreach ($data as $item => $audits)
                                                <div>
                                                    <span class="audit-daily-text39"><strong
                                                            style="font-size: 13px;">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($audits->data_audit)->format('d/m') }}</strong></span>
                                                </div>
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `$audits` is an array, not an object

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I tried that too : $audits['data_audit'] , but it gives me key error in the array

Comment: can you help me replace the code? I'm going crazy.. thank you so much

Comment: Did you `dd($audits)` (or `dump($audits)`) to check what it contains?

Comment: contains multy array

Comment: I would like to see this type of graph.. post the photo..

Comment: I would like to see this type of graph.. post the photo.. db and graph

Comment: you need to loop audits again if you want to access the underlying attributes such as `data_audit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="audit-daily-intestazione">
    @if (!empty($data))
        @foreach ($data as $item => $audits)
            <div>
                @foreach ($audits as $audit)
                    <span class="audit-daily-text39">
                    <strong style="font-size: 13px;">
                        {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($audit['data_audit'])->format('d/m') }}
                    </strong>
                </span>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Correct thank you..